# Using Excel Formula functions (ERF, ERFC) in Excel VBA code?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use the error function and the complimentary error function in my program. Neither are working. I keep getting the error `Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined`. However, if I go into a cell and manually try to use the error function, it works.

Why is that? How can I use it in my actual code?

The error function is `ERF(x)` and the complimentary error function is `ERFC(x)`.

Here's an example of things that don't work:

```
Sub SeriouslyWHYIsntThisWorking()
    x = 3
    Range("A1") = Erf(x)
End Sub
```

Even this doesn't work:

```
Sub PleaseWork()
    Range("A1") = Erfc(1)
End Sub
```

But if I went into Excel and typed `=ERF(3)` or `=ERFC(1)` into a cell, it'll work.

I'm very new to this and probably missing something incredibly simple. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a worksheet formula in vba, you need to put `Application.WorksheetFunction.` in front of it.

Some functions do have vba equivalents, but (as far as I know) not in the case of `erf` and `erfc`

Comment: Oh, I had no idea that not all of them had vba equivalents. Thank you!

Comment: example: `=FIND(`: while you could use `application.worksheet.find(`, it would be better to use the vba function `InStr`

Comment: This still doesn't address the need for the add-in to be installed.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have the Analysis Toolpak for VBA add-in installed/referenced? (Look for atpvbaen.xls)

The `ERF` function is part of that add-in, and there are two versions of it (one for use in Excel functions, and one for VBA), and you'll need the right one set up and referenced by your project to be usable.

The add-ins are standard from MSFT, but not always set up by default. If you can use it in Excel normally, then you've already set up at least the Excel version. So using it all like it looks like you want to do will require the add-in, regardless of how you implement/use that function. Meaning, if you want to share this with anyone else, they will need the add-in installed/activated.

---

To link together this answer with the others provided (which are equally accurate and correct), either setting a cell value with

`Range("A1").value = Application.WorksheetFunction.ERF(x)`

or setting a cell formula with

`Range("A1").Formula = "=Erfc(" + x + ")"`

will require the end-user using the add-in.

Comment: I definitely do not have that installed. Thanks for letting me know!


This program is going to be used by many different people, however, so I can't use that to fix this particular issue. I'm using the solution one above though, and it works.

Comment: @TheTreeMan But if your end users do not have the AnalysisToolpak (non-VBA version) installed correctly, the `ERF/ERFC` formulas (even if input directly into the cell) will not work for them.

Comment: I confused myself. I mean that I added Application.Worksheetfunction in front of the ERF and it worked.

Comment: @TheTreeMan And that will *still* require the add-in.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Sub ThisShouldWorkNow()
    x = 3
    formula = "=Erfc(" + x + ")"
    Range("A1").Formula = formula
End Sub
```

Totally untested, since I don't have Excel on my Linux machine... But I think I'm getting the point across -- you need to use the .Formula property of the Range object.

There's more information here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg192736.aspx